# Coin change problem - need asssitance with additional contraints

Tags: c#, dynamic, structure, knapsack-problem

I am trying to a variation of the coin change problem with 2 additional constraints.

Additional Constraint #1 - Coins can only have value of 2^N where N = 0,1,2.. or any other non-negative integer

Additional Constraint #2 - You can only use the same coin up to 2 times from constraint 1

What I have done so far is :-

1 . Generate a list of values which are applicable for the sum we wish to attain where, so

Eg:- For 6 , I would generate a list containing [1,2,4]

2. Generate a list which contains value for how many times you can use a specific coin , according to constraint #2 , this would be 2 for all cases, hence ,

[2,2,2] for [1,2,4].

I am unsure of how am I supposed to combined these 2 lists to get the expected output. What I have so far is:-

```
static int Ways(List<int> coins, List<int> coins_used,  int sum)
{
    int[] no_of_ways = new int[sum + 1]; 
    results[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.Count; i++)
        for (int times = 0; times < coins_used[i]; times++) // I want to make sure that we use one value only up to 2 times
            for (int j = coins[i]; j <= sum; j++)
                no_of_ways[j] += no_of_ways[j - times*coins[i]];
    return no_of_ways[sum];
}
```

Expected Result : - For sum = 6, the function should return 3 since we can represent 6 in 3 different ways which are {1,1,4} , {1,1,2,2} , {2,4}

Actual Result : the function returns 17